# Writing a novel past tense confusion

Tags: grammar

I was taught to pick a tense when writing a story. So normally I choose past tense. But how to deal with this ambiguity?

- John was brave the day before.
- John was a kind person.

Does this mean John is no longer kind?

In the story time line John is still brave as of now. But since the story happened in the past I have to use "was". How can I convey presentness within the past?

English is not my first language. I hope this make some sort of sense!

Comment: This is the phrase *John is brave yesterday*, backshifted so it is in the past. It doesn't make much sense in the present tense, and it makes equally little sense in the past.

Comment: Descriptions of people in a story refer to the time in which the events were happening, whether that is a hundred years ago or yesterday. 'John was kind' is how the other characters experienced him; it is not ambiguous. Sometimes, though, an author may tell a story through the eyes of one character and have them tell the reader that things are different now.

Answer (score 1):

Since everything usually in the present tense has been shifted to past tense, technically speaking everything in the past tense should be backshifted again to pluperfect (past perfect): John had been brave the day before, but he was cowardly today.

But if you have a long line of events that happened in the past, it's usually sufficient to use the pluperfect only for the first verb and simple past for the rest; the reader will understand that the entire "scene" is in the past.